# How do I stop Ubuntu Precise freezing/hanging

Tags: 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

At least once a day I lose work on my (2 different) Intel i5 machines running Ubuntu 12.04. The entire system will freeze/lock-up/hang, and never return. At this point nothing works; even the caps lock key doesn't toggle the light on the keyboard; Ctrl-Alt-F1 won't do anything either.

askubuntu.com is apparently where I'm directed for support.

I suspect this is a kernel bug. But I simply can't keep losing work like this, so I'm anxious to try whatever it takes to get the thing reliably working.

Can you suggest

1. something I can try to fix the problem
2. an existing bug I can follow progress on and contribute to (from users/tester's POV)
3. the most constructive way I can contribute to helping fix the problem, keeping in mind that I do need the computer (so can't do things that might "brick" it!)

Comment: You should be able to elegantly reboot your system by pressing Alt - SysRq (both at the same time) and combine with these, one after the other: r e i s u b (aka the magic SysRq key http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key). Could you report back if this works for you or not? You could also check in var/log/syslog and var/log/kern.log (open the log files in gedit) if something out of the ordinary has happened at the time of the freeze/lockup. If there is something, copy the relevant messages to pastebin.com and post the link in your question.

Comment: You should report this issue as a bug in launchpad.net, they will guide you and help you sort out if there is another bug already open with it.

Comment: @Tinellus Will try the magic SysRq thing on my box that *has* a SysRq button (the laptop doesn't). There is nothing in syslog, guess it doesn't have time to write it. @Bruno i guess you mean `ubuntu-bug linux` ?

Comment: if you have a "Print Screen" button you can use Ctrl + Alt + PrtScrn....just incase you were overlooking that key on your laptop

Comment: Thanks, not had much success with that in the past, perhaps I'm [running out of fingers!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key#Commands). Will report back when I crash it today.

Comment: Yep, unresponsive to Alt-SysRq.

Answer (score 0):

Just wait, keep `apt-get dist-upgrade`ing and hope things get better.

At least that's the only option I found available. And hey, they did get better. Still using 12.04 and now very rare to have a full freeze after a successful boot.

Comment: ah, shucks, back again. [filed bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1046898)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues using 64bit 12.04.1... including mouse problems.  I reinstalled and am slowly reloading applications to ID the issue.  Ubuntu Forums discussions point to the use of Chrome or Chromium (in my case).  After reinstalling, I am using only Firefox for the past 4 days and have not seen a lockup.  Still reintroducing applications, but so far, I've avoided Chromium and the freezes are gone.

Comment: interesting! I do use Chromium sometimes. However, have def. had freezes without it.