# ubuntu 13.04 hang problem when ever i press the chipset driver button such as display or sound button

Tags: 13.04

I have just installed Ubuntu 13.04 on my Dell Inspiron N5010.

Whenever I press the  display brightness button, the OS hangs up

Answer (score 0):

Check out your syslog after the reboot to try to isolate what it called and try this out ...

[What is the equivalent of 'Control-Alt-Delete'?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95192/what-is-the-equivalent-of-control-alt-delete)

**Other possibilities:**
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12107/how-to-unfreeze-after-accidentally-pressing-ctrl-s-in-a-terminal
[How do I stop Ubuntu Precise freezing/hanging](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156690/how-do-i-stop-ubuntu-precise-freezing-hanging)